# Toggle on and off with jQuery

Tags: jquery, label

My aim is simple—have my tick/cross toggle on and off (red or green) as the toggle fires.

I have tried so many variations of jQuery but for some reason nothing works.

Here is a link to a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t7nep473/

HTML:

```
<div class="three columns"> 
  <label class="toggle">
    <i class="fa fa-close toggle-off active"></i>
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-input">
    <div class="toggle-controller default-success"></div>
    <i class="fa fa-check toggle-on"></i>
  </label><!-- END .toggle -->
</div><!-- END .three.columns -->
```

CSS:

```
.toggle {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 7.5rem;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle-input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.toggle-off,
.toggle-on {
  height: 1.8125rem;
  width: 1.8125rem;
  color: rgba(46, 45, 44, 0.1);
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.8125rem !important;
}
.toggle-input:checked + .toggle-controller.default-success {
  border: 0.125rem solid rgba(108, 211, 61, 0.75);
  background: rgba(108, 211, 61, 0.375);
}
.toggle-input:checked + .toggle-controller.default-success:after {
  left: 1.5625rem;
}
.toggle-controller.default-success {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.5625rem;
  width: 3.125rem;
  border: 0.125rem solid rgba(46, 45, 44, 0.05);
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.5625rem;
  -moz-border-radius: 1.5625rem;
  border-radius: 1.5625rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.1875rem rgba(46, 45, 44, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.1875rem rgba(46, 45, 44, 0.25);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.1875rem rgba(46, 45, 44, 0.25);
  background: rgba(46, 45, 44, 0.025);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.toggle-controller.default-success:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1.5625rem;
  width: 1.5625rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.5625rem;
  -moz-border-radius: 1.5625rem;
  border-radius: 1.5625rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.0625rem 0.125rem rgba(46, 45, 44, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0.0625rem 0.125rem rgba(46, 45, 44, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0.0625rem 0.125rem rgba(46, 45, 44, 0.2);
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
.toggle-off.active {color:red;}
.toggle-on.active {color:green;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        if($(this).find('.toggle-off').hasClass('active')) {
            console.log('This is firing');
            $(this).find('.toggle-off').removeClass('active');
            $(this).find('.toggle-on').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).find('.toggle-off').addClass('active');
            $(this).find('.toggle-on').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

**Note:** I'm using the Font Awesome Library.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nice edit on the title ;)

Comment: The problem in you code is the click event is firing two times.

Comment: @KishoreSahas I noticed this in the console when trying to solve this earlier. What in my code is firing the click event twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler on `.toggle-input` and check if `$(this)` [`.is(':checked')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-input').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            console.log('This is firing');
            $('.toggle-off').removeClass('active');
            $('.toggle-on').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.toggle-off').addClass('active');
            $('.toggle-on').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7nep473/1/)

Comment: can you not just use `toggleClass` instead? all you're doing is changing the active class.

Comment: @RobScott: For sure there are several ways to accomplish what the OP wants. Mine is only one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @D4VID.

Comment: @RobScott unless there is a gap in my understanding of the jQuery library, .toggleClass would not suffice as it is only effective when initially subtracting a class (then re-adding). As there are two elements (one with and one without) the .active class in the markup's original state .toggleClass wouldn't suit. Could be way off though...

Comment: please see the below answer with toggleClass()

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').change(function() {
        $(this).find('.toggle-on').toggleClass('active');
        $(this).find('.toggle-off').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t7nep473/4/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the click is binded to `label`.

We can fix this by adding `return false;`

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.toggle').click(function() {
            if($(this).find('.toggle-off').hasClass('active')) {
                console.log('This is firing');
                $(this).find('.toggle-off').removeClass('active');
                $(this).find('.toggle-on').addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).find('.toggle-off').addClass('active');
                $(this).find('.toggle-on').removeClass('active');
            }
           return false;
        });
     });
```

The actual problem is explained below.

Essentially since clicking the label also causes a native click event to be thrown on the associated input element, a click event may be handled twice if the input element is a child of the label (implicit association). Messes with event delegation a bit also.

Ref : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10673

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for linking me through to the bug.

Comment: Welcome !! I hope this is more suitable answer when compared to others, if you think so, please accept this answer. so that it will be help full for others!!